# Reliability of Mobile Application Blocks Community Release

Tags: windows-mobile, application-blocks

This question relates to my previous one on [Using only parts of Mobile Application Blocks Community Release for WM 6.x Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377833/using-only-parts-of-mobile-application-blocks-community-release-for-wm-6-x-develo)

Most of my questions were answered there, but still have one open issue left.

A community driven successor to [MCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648751.aspx) is [Mobile Application Blocks Community Release](http://mobile.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Changes%20from%20MCSF%20v1&referringTitle=Home) and [Mobile Contribute](http://mobilecontrib.codeplex.com/) extension to that release.

What I am interested in is an opinion from someone who has implemented a solution based on those, not MCSF, which I know by now, is something that I need to stay away from, as DI/IoC framework used there maps to horrible performance on the mobile device. Yet, since that part has been reworked in [MAB](http://mobile.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Changes%20from%20MCSF%20v1&referringTitle=Home), I am interested in knowing, whether the rework is as good as it seems based on what I could find about on [its author blog](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/mobile-application-blocks-containermodel-funq-an-introduction/).

Anyone here wrote a real world line of business solution using those new blocks and has a minute to share his experience?